# formatting individual link with linkifyjs

Tags: javascript, linkify

I cant understand how I can format few links in individual way... for example github.com with rel:follow (not working). How I can building something like a IF: `if(url==mywebiste.com){rel: follow}` in const options?? is it possible? https://linkify.js.org/docs/options.html#format

```
const beforeEl = document.getElementById('linkify-demo-before')
const afterEl = document.getElementById('linkify-demo-after')

const options = {
  title: "External Link",
  rel: 'nofollow noreferrer noopener',
  target: '_blank',

  formatHref: {
    hashtag: (val) => `https://www.twitter.com/hashtag/${val.substr(1)}`,
    mention: (val) => `https://github.com/${val.substr(1)}`,
  }
}

linkifyHtml("github.com", {
  rel: 'follow',
 });

afterEl.innerHTML = linkifyStr(beforeEl.value, options)
beforeEl.addEventListener('input', () => {
  afterEl.innerHTML = linkifyStr(beforeEl.value, options)
  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Most options in linkifyjs, including `rel`, accept a function. For each link encountered, this function is called with the `href` as the first argument and the type of link as the second argument.

Example options with the behaviour you're looking for:

```js
const options = {
  rel: (href, type) => {
    if (type === 'url' && href.startsWith('https://mywebsite.com') {
        return null;
    } else {
        return 'nofollow noreferrer noopener'
    }
  }
}

const linkified = linkifyStr("... https://mywebsite.com/about ...", options)
console.log(linkified)
```